# Fill xhtml table with postgres database info

Tags: html, postgresql, html-table, xhtml

I have three tables in PostgreSQL. Movies (**id**, title, director and length), Users (**id**, first and last name) and Rentals (**user id** and **movie id**).

In my xhtml, I want to have a table that fills with the information of the Rental table PLUS all of the info from those keys of the other tables. Basically, I'll do:

```
SELECT u.*, m.* FROM rentals r
join users u on
r.iduser = u.id
join movies m on
r.idmovie = m.id;
```

I want to put the results of that query in an xhtml table like so:

```
<f:view>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr><th colspan="99">Active Rentals</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th colspan="3">User Information</th>
            <th width="30"></th>
            <th colspan="4">Movie Information</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Director</th><th>Length</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <!-- To be repeated and filled with the info. -->
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>id</td><td>first name</td><td>last name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>id</td><td>title</td><td>director</td><td>length</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</f:view>
```

But I genuinelly dont know how to achieve this. Using .zul I could use something called `<template>` that would be loaded from a model of the result of the query and would fill that template as many times as needed and add them eacht as a new row in the table.

Is there a similar approach to this but in xhtml? If not, how do I fill the table?